# Unity game scene is not in full screen on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'am having problem making my app be full screen on all device. on my device, w/c is a low end Jelly bean phone doesn't give me the right resolution I want.

Here is my desired output:

[image: Desired output(this is still in editor)]

this is still in editor, resolution  1080px by 1920px in Portrait mode

here is the output on my device:

[image]

as you can see, you can see a blue part on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your background is visible from behind your geometry, the aspect ratio of two screenshot is different. It looks like you designed the game in a 278x490 resolution (aspect 1:1.762) and displaying it in a 480x800 resolution (aspect ratio 1:1.666).

You should always design for the lowest possible aspect ratio, then you don't have this problem.

You have two solutions:

1. You should add some walls/roofs to make margins that will be visible on wider devices
2. You can shorten the length of the corridor by scaling the game field up so the width fits.

Comment: aren't there any way too just simply make my app be flexible on every device?

Comment: These are the ways, and they are quite simple already. 

If you want more specific answers, they will be dependent on how you have made your game - you have to refine your question for that.